# variable for randomly generated key in database rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I would like to access the variable that is the randomly generated key during the "push" operation in the .child method in my rule. How can I do this. below in my "Projects" rule $itemId works.

but in my Assets rule im trying to check against a parent item and pass in $itemid to a .child method and it does not work. again to be clear, $itemId should be the value of the randomy generated key during the push operation as it is in my Projects rule tree. I believe the problem is $itemId is not available in the scope of Assets rule but not sure how to fix that without having to re-structure my database significantly.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Projects": {
        "$itemId": {
          ".read": "auth !== null || data.child('public').val() == true",
          ".write": "auth !== null"
        }
    },
    "users": {
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth !== null"
    },
    "Assets": {
        ".read": "auth !== null || data.parent().child('Projects').child($itemId).child('public').val() == true",
        ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you push something to Projects, then nothing under Assets will be affected, and therefore no rule nested under Assets will trigger.  Why are you expecting something different?

Comment: I see what you are saying. What im trying to accomplish is if someone wants to access assets, it checks if the project is "public" and if so, grants access to the asset.  So my asset rule is trying to check the "public" field in Projects basically. I guess the real soluton here is to add a "public" field to my assets database the same way I am with Projects. I was trying to link the two with one public flag.

Comment: I think you might want to read the documentation on accessing other parts of the database within a rule, so that you can read from Projects when someone writes to Assets.